# Increase font size with unicode in java

Tags: java

I have been given a task where entered string should be printed in increased/larger size with the help of unicode.
This is my code so far but it does not produce correct output.

```
String str = "hi";
System.out.println(str+ "\uD83D\uDDDA");
```

Can anyone tell me where is it getting wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "increased size"? You can't control the *size* of a rendered glyph using unicode.

Comment: @aioobe it means that if size of font is 12 then it should be printed in larger size say 16

Comment: That doesn't really have to do with unicode. You must have misunderstood the task, or the person who asked you to do this has no clue what unicode is.

Comment: For other readers: `D83D DDDA` is UTF-16 for `` ([`1F5DA` Increase Font Size Symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f5da/index.htm)).

Comment: @Masu The "Increase Font Size Symbol" is a symbol (pictograph), not an instruction to change font size.

Comment: @Andreas then what way can i enlarge font size using unicode?

Comment: There is no way.  Your teacher is leading you up the garden path!

Comment: @Masu You can't.  Unicode is a scheme for representing _plain_ text as a sequence of numbers.  It has nothing to do with representing or rendering _rich_ text (i.e, text with font changes and formatting and etc.)  The main difference between Unicode and everything that came before Unicode is that Unicode is meant to work for _all_ human languages.

Comment: @Andreas - Yes. But that is not what the OP means; see his comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the task given to you is to print the input in Unicode Fullwidth Forms. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms#In_Unicode).

Example:

```
Input:  HELLO
Output: ＨＥＬＬＯ
```

You should check out this web page for other options:
http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=How+well+does+this+work%3F

Comment: the task is:
if word hello has font size 12, then it should be enlarged to size 16 when user chooses to enlarge it.

thank you for the link. I'll check it for help.

Comment: That task has nothing to do with unicode as far as I can tell.